# Why is the React portal a state?

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

The docs on react portals: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Like the title asks, I am not really sure why a portal is a state. I am asking about the technicalities about rendering and re-rendering, or if there are some other underlying reasons.

Why should it be in a state, like this:

```
const [container] = useState(document.createElement('div'));
```

and not just a regular variable, like this:

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
```

EDIT:

When I have the container in a `useState()` it will update and re-render the content/children without any interruptions. When the container is outside of state, the updates will be choppy.

Comment: where does it mention being in state in those docs?

Comment: @MattAft Good point. Though when I've looked around, it seems that using it with a `useState()` is quite common. When I exclude it, and update the portal content without removing the portal, it will be removed and re-rendered, instead of just re-rendering.

Comment: I've found that using `useMemo` is sufficient, since the "state" is never updated anyway, so I just do `const container = useMemo(() => document.createElement('div'), [])` in my portal containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing `const container = document.createElement('div');` will create a new div each re-render, but by storing it in a state that is unchanged, react will only run that code once and keep hold of that element.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate approach. Instead of adding the createElement calls inside a state variable, I simply moved them out of the react component.

Instead of this

```js
const ModalContainer = (props) => {
  const [modalSection] = useState(document.createElement('section'));
  //do stuff
}
```

do this

```js
const modalSection = document.createElement('section');

const ModalContainer = (props) => {
 // Do stuff
 // return stuff
}
```